# Use cloud-init to change root password before first login

Tags: ansible, cloud-init

I'm using a new VPS hoster, which assigns a random root password to a newly-created Debian VPS and emails it to me. With my current VPS hoster, I can specify the root password myself when I create the VPS. This difference means my ansible playbook no longer works.

I can provide a `cloud-init` script, and thought to use it to specify a root password:

```yaml
#cloud-config
chpasswd:
  expire: false
  users:
    - name: root
      password: my_password
      type: text
runcmd:
  - touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

I hoped that would change the root password and disable cloud-init; thereafter I intended to provision the server with ansible as usual.

But that doesn't work - when I log in it still expects the original password created by the hosting company, rather than the one I specified (`my_password`).

Is this because the script runs on login, rather that on boot? How can I fix this?

Comment: That should work, though that "users" syntax is newer. What version of cloud-init are you running? Are there any WARNINGs or Tracebacks in /var/log/cloud-init.log?

Comment: @falcojr It's running on the latest debian, so version 22.4.2. There are no error/warn logs.